# How to pass URL from instance to function in WP Widget

Tags: php, wordpress, function, widget, instance

I'm trying to create simple widget that return images with available thumbnails from single URL. I can't figure it out, how to pass url stored in instance `$chosen_image_url;` to `$image_url = '';` .
Please Help.
Widget code:

```
class MyWidget extends WP_Widget {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
        'mywidget_widget', 
        __( 'My Widget', 'text_domain' ), 
        array( 'description' => __( 'My Widget', 'text_domain' ), ) 
    );
}
public function widget($args, $instance) { 
    extract( $args );
    $chosen_image_url = ! empty( $instance['chosen_image_url'] ) ? $instance['chosen_image_url'] : '';
    echo $before_widget;

    echo $chosen_image_url; // works fine, return stored url 
    $image_url = 'http://my-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/chosen-images.jpg';  // image url need to be --- $chosen_image_url !!!!!!!!!
    $image_id = pippin_get_image_id($image_url); // store the image ID in a var
    $image_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'large'); // retrieve the thumbnail size of our image
    echo $image_thumb[0]; // works fine, display the image thumb - large 

echo $after_widget; 
}
function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['chosen_image_url'] = esc_url( $new_instance['chosen_image_url'] );
    return $instance;
}
function form( $instance ) {
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array(
        'chosen_image_url' =>  '',
    ) );
    $chosen_image_url = esc_url( $instance['chosen_image_url'] );
?>
<p>
<label for="
<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'chosen_image_url' ); ?>">
    <?php _e( 'Image URL', 'mywidget_widget' ); ?>:</label>
<br />
<input type="text" class="img widefat" name="
<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'chosen_image_url' ); ?>" id="
<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'chosen_image_url' ); ?>" value="
<?php echo $chosen_image_url; ?>" />
<br />
<input type="button" class="select-img button button-primary" value="
<?php _e( 'Upload', 'mywidget_widget' ); ?>" data-uploader_title="
<?php _e( 'Select Image', 'mywidget_widget' ); ?>" data-uploader_button_text="
<?php _e( 'Choose Image', 'mywidget_widget' ); ?>" style="margin:10px 0;" />
</p>
<?php
}
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
register_widget( 'MyWidget' );
});
?>
```

for Attachment ID in function.php

```
function pippin_get_image_id($image_url) {
global $wpdb;
$attachment = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='%s';", $image_url )); 
    return $attachment[0]; 
}
```

any help is very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Solved add `$image_url = $instance['chosen_image_url'];` to function widget.

Comment: Your answer would benefit from adding some explanation